# ABI encode external function call with multiple arguments in Huff

Tags: abi, encoding, huff

I am trying to make an external function call, with multiple arguments, to a contract written in Solidity from a contract written in Huff. I am able to successfully call an external contract when the function accepts a single argument, however when it accepts two or more arguments, the fallback function is always triggered and caused the transaction to revert. I know this because if I will add a simple fallback function that does nothing, then the transaction doesn't revert anymore. This tells me that the issue is something to do with the ABI encoding of the function call. I have created a set of files to reproduce the issue and please note that I am using Foundry and foundry-huff for development.

Counter.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: BSL-1.1
pragma solidity 0.8.19;

contract Counter {
    uint256 public count;

    constructor() {}

    // fallback() external {} // uncomment to stop tests from failing

    function increaseA(uint256 amount_) public {
        count += amount_;
    }

    function increaseB(uint256 amount1_, uint256 amount2_) public {
        count += (amount1_ + amount2_);
    }
}
```

HuffCounter.huff:

```
/// @title HuffCounter
/// @notice SPDX-License-Identifier: BSL-1.1

/* Interface */
#define function increaseA(address, uint256) nonpayable returns ()
#define function increaseB(address, uint256, uint256) nonpayable returns ()

/* Constructor */
#define macro CONSTRUCTOR() = takes (0) returns (0) {}

/* Methods */    
#define macro INCREASE_COUNT_A() = takes(0) returns (0) {
    __FUNC_SIG("increaseA(uint256)") 0x00 mstore
    0x24 calldataload
    0x20 mstore

    0x00                // [ret_size]
    0x00                // [ret_offset, ret_size]
    0x24                // [args_size, ret_offset, ret_size]
    0x1C                // [args_offset, args_size, ret_offset, ret_size]
    0x00                // [value, args_offset, args_size, ret_offset, ret_size]
    0x04 calldataload   // [counter_addr, value, args_offset, args_size, ret_offset, ret_size]
    gas                 // [gas, counter_addr, value, args_offset, args_size, ret_offset, ret_size]
    call                // [successs]

    0x00 eq err jumpi
    cont jump

    err:
        0x00 0x00 revert
    cont:
        0x00 0x00 return
}

#define macro INCREASE_COUNT_B() = takes(0) returns (0) {
    __FUNC_SIG("increaseB(uint256, uint256)") 0x00 mstore
    0x24 calldataload
    0x20 mstore
    0x44 calldataload
    0x40 mstore

    0x00                // [ret_size]
    0x00                // [ret_offset, ret_size]
    0x44                // [args_size, ret_offset, ret_size]
    0x1C                // [args_offset, args_size, ret_offset, ret_size]
    0x00                // [value, args_offset, args_size, ret_offset, ret_size]
    0x04 calldataload   // [counter_addr, value, args_offset, args_size, ret_offset, ret_size]
    gas                 // [gas, counter_addr, value, args_offset, args_size, ret_offset, ret_size]
    call                // [successs]

    0x00 eq err jumpi
    cont jump

    err:
        0x00 0x00 revert
    cont:
        0x00 0x00 return
}

#define macro MAIN() = takes (0) returns (0) {
    // Identify which function is being called.
    0x00 calldataload 0xE0 shr
    
    dup1 __FUNC_SIG(increaseA) eq increaseA jumpi
    dup1 __FUNC_SIG(increaseB) eq increaseB jumpi

    0x00 0x00 revert

    increaseA:
        INCREASE_COUNT_A()
    increaseB:
        INCREASE_COUNT_B()
}
```

Counter.t.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.15;

import "forge-std/Test.sol";
import "foundry-huff/HuffDeployer.sol";
import "forge-std/console.sol";

import {Counter} from "src/Counter.sol";

contract BundleExecutorTest is Test {
    Counter public counter;
    IHuffCounter public huffCounter;

    function setUp() public {
        counter = new Counter();
        huffCounter = IHuffCounter(HuffDeployer.deploy("HuffCounter"));
    }

    function testIncreaseA() public {
        huffCounter.increaseA(address(counter), 3);

        uint256 count_ = counter.count();

        console.log(count_);
    }

    function testIncreaseB() public {
        huffCounter.increaseB(address(counter), 3, 4);

        uint256 count_ = counter.count();

        console.log(count_);
    }
}

interface IHuffCounter {
    function increaseA(address, uint256) external;
    function increaseB(address, uint256, uint256) external;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function signature of of `increaseB` should be `increaseB(uint256,uint256)`, not `increaseB(uint256, uint256)`. Function sigs are hashed with no spaces between words or letters. Your encoding of parameters and everything else LGTM